# Linq Joins only working when all tables have data

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, join

Below you can find my problem. My view only loops through the data when both of "DocentenCompetenties" and "DocentenLocaties" is filled in. This is a problen because I want to be able to loop them even if one of them doens't have any data

```
var ShowCompetenties = from d in db.Docent
      join dc in db.DocentenCompetenties on d.DocentID equals dc.DocentID
      join c in db.Competenties on dc.CompetentiesID equals c.CompetentiesID
      join dl in db.DocentenLocaties on d.DocentID equals dl.DocentID
      where d.DocentID == id
      join l in db.Locaties on dl.LocatieID equals l.LocatieID
      select new ShowCompetenties { Docenten = d, Competenties = c, DocentenCompetenties = dc, DocentenLocaties = dl, Locaties = l };
```

**UPDATE**

***Current Error:*** 
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_xp01otas.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
    var LeftShowCompetenties = from d in db.Docent
       join g1 in db.DocentenCompetenties on d.DocentID equals g1.DocentID into group1
       from dc in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()                                    
       join c in db.Competenties on dc.CompetentiesID equals c.CompetentiesID
       where d.DocentID == id                          
       select new ShowCompetenties { Docenten = d, Competenties = c, DocentenCompetenties = dc};


    var RightShowCompetenties = from d in db.Docent                                         
        join g3 in db.DocentenLocaties on d.DocentID equals g3.DocentID into group3      from dl in group3.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where d.DocentID == id
        join l in db.Locaties on dl.LocatieID equals l.LocatieID
        select new ShowCompetenties { Docenten = d, Locaties = l, DocentenLocaties = dl };



    var ShowCompetenties = LeftShowCompetenties.Union(RightShowCompetenties);
```

**VIEW**

```
<h4>Competenties</h4>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
            if(@item.DocentenCompetenties != null && @item.DocentenCompetenties.DocentID.ToString() != null) { 
            @item.Competenties.Name @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCompetenties", new { id = item.DocentenCompetenties.DocentenCompetentiesID })
}

 <h4>Docenten</h4>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
      if(@item.DocentenLocaties != null && @item.DocentenLocaties .DocentID.ToString() != null) 
        {
            @item.Locaties.Name
        }
}
```

Comment: Look at [DefaultIfEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360179(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: im working with @foreach(var item in **Model**)
{ @item.Locaties.Name } I tries but it failed. Should I rewrite the query?

Comment: Goes without saying, if you have to do joins in LINQ, something is probably wrong - at the very least, there's a missing relation between the entities. Worst case, LINQ is used as an alternative to SQL (it's not) and the entire join should be replaced with a VIEW. At least, create **proper relations** in your model/mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing an Inner join this way.

It sounds like you actually want to do an outer join.
Try this:

```
var ShowCompetenties = from d in db.Docent
  join g1 in db.DocentenCompetenties on d.DocentID equals g1.DocentID into group1
  from dc in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()

  join g2 in db.Competenties on dc.CompetentiesID equals g2.CompetentiesID into group2
  from c in group2.DefaultIfEmpty()

  join g3 in db.DocentenLocaties on d.DocentID equals g3.DocentID into group3
  from dl in group3.DefaultIfEmpty()

  where d.DocentID == id
  join l in db.Locaties on dl.LocatieID equals l.LocatieID
  select new ShowCompetenties { Docenten = d, Competenties = c, DocentenCompetenties = dc, DocentenLocaties = dl, Locaties = l };
```

This is only a LEFT outer join however, if you wish to do a full outer join. You must first do a left, then a right outer join and finally merge (with `Union()`) the two.

EDIT
As per the comments, with regards to the error you're getting after the `UNION`:

```
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
        var LeftShowCompetenties = from d in db.Docent
            join g1 in db.DocentenCompetenties on d.DocentID equals g1.DocentID into group1
            from dc in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()                                    
            join c in db.Competenties on dc.CompetentiesID equals c.CompetentiesID
            where d.DocentID == id                          
            select new ShowCompetenties { Docenten = d, Competenties = c, Locaties = null, DocentenCompetenties = dc, DocentenLocaties = null};


    var RightShowCompetenties = from d in db.Docent                                         
           join g3 in db.DocentenLocaties on d.DocentID equals g3.DocentID into group3
           from dl in group3.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where d.DocentID == id
           join l in db.Locaties on dl.LocatieID equals l.LocatieID
           select new ShowCompetenties { Docenten = d, Competenties = null, Locaties = l, DocentenCompetenties = null, DocentenLocaties = dl };



   var ShowCompetenties = LeftShowCompetenties.Union(RightShowCompetenties);
```

(Check the added `Locaties = null` and `Competenties = null` in the constructors.)

**VIEW**

```
if (@item.DocentenCompetenties != null){}
if (@item.DocentenLocaties!= null){}
```

Comment: Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397908.aspx it provides some more explanation about all this. And for creating a right join: you basicly switch the tables around in your joins. There are plenty of examples out there if you wish more details.

Comment: The type 'DocentenAlumniAPP.Models.ShowCompetenties' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query Error I get when following the examples

Comment: That sounds like the constructor in your select is different in the left join vs the right join. (That error is usually thrown during the `Union()`) Can you post your complete query?

Comment: Ah yes, you 'must' use a similar constructor. I'll update my answer with a sample that should work. EDIT: Updated it.

Comment: **Same error here:**
Line 61: @foreach (var item in Model)
The type 'DocentenAlumniAPP.Models.ShowCompetenties' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

Comment: Aha, Seems like I missed the last parameter, thought they were the same.  (`DocentenLocaties` and `DocentenCompetenties`) Updated my answer again.

Comment: _Bummer, another error:_ An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_xp01otas.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. **Note** Every table has the right data

Comment: I assume that error is given further down the line? Because we have to set some variables to NULL in the constructors before the union, you will have to change your other code to add some nullchecks where required.

Comment: You can check my view if you like, I updated my question

Comment: Yep, both `@item.DocentenCompetenties` and `@item.DocentenLocaties` could now actually be NULL. You will have to add an if-check for that.

Comment: I added an if-statement like you can see, so it's not enough?

Comment: Those will throw the NullReferenceException if `@item.DocentenCompetenties` is null. Try this: `if(@item.DocentenCompetenties != null && @item.DocentenCompetenties.DocentID.ToString() != null)` (and likewise for the other statement.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_sen2uh1f.dll but was not handled in user code (going crazy)

Comment: **This is highlighted** if(@item.DocentenCompetenties != null && @item.DocentenCompetenties.DocentID.ToString() != null)

Comment: I presume you can debug that exception? If so, you can actually check each variable and property, see if e.g. @item or one of its descendants is null.

Comment: No, I can't debug it. It is saying that it's null but it can't be.

Comment: I'm not that used to ASP.NET, but it may be that this error is getting thrown because the code isn't completely interpreted as code. I understand that wrapping the foreaches in `@{` and `}` should do it. See e.g. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/01/09/ten-tricks-for-razor-views.aspx

Comment: @SaraBarreraRiano - the error is occurring at this point because item.DocentenCompetenties.DocentID can't use the ToString() method if it's null. Your basically saying convert DocentID to a string, which it can't do if it's null. It's trying to do this BEFORE you then check if it's null. Take off the ToString() for this check.

Answer (score 1):

If you have navigation properties set up, it's much easier to left join:

```
var ShowCompetenties =
  from d in db.Docent
  where d.DocentID == id
  from dc in d.DocentenCompetenties.DefaultIfEmpty()
  let c = dc.Competenty
  from dl in d.DocentenLocaties.DefaultIfEmpty()
  let l = dl.Locaty
  select new ShowCompetenties {
    Docenten = d,
    Competenties = c,
    DocentenCompetenties = dc,
    DocentenLocaties = dl,
    Locaties = l };
```

Comment: **the joins I have are working I think, I am just struggling with this error now** An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_q05ilzt1.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @SaraBarreraRiano if you have to use joins, then the LINQ mapping is broken. There's no benefit in using an ORM if you have to use join entities by hand, but this *is* causing a lot of problems - relation code is spread across all controllers in the form of joins when it should be a few lines of code in the DbContext's configuration

Comment: So this is a better solution?